# Draw pyramid in half sphere, pointing to some direction

Tags: c++, opengl, math, random

I have a point randomly generated, with some random direction(with random lat and random lon) which I calculate by these mathematical equations:

```
dirX = cos(lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * sin(lon * DEG_TO_RAD);
dirY = sin(lat * DEG_TO_RAD);
dirZ = cos(lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * cos(lon * DEG_TO_RAD);
```

What i would like is to take that point, and draw a pyramid. This pyramid has its square base on the half of the sphere, the point that is generated should be the center of this square.

Then according to the direction of the point, I would like to generate the coordinates of this pyramid, which should be located on the spherical periphery that a sphere with radius r would have, which has the random point as it's center.

The top of the pyramid point to the direction the random point has, and the other points should be drawn respectively. This is a picture to help you imagine what I am trying to do.

[Pyramid in half sphere Sketch](http://s887.photobucket.com/user/nicos9pavlou/media/Untitled_zps973af498.png.html)

This is what I am doing:

```
//A
v[0][0][0]= radius *  (cos(lat) * sin(lon));
v[0][0][1]= radius * sin(lat);
v[0][0][2]= radius * (cos(lat) * cos(lon));

    //B
v[0][2][0]= radius *  (cos(lat+(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * sin(lon));
v[0][3][1]= radius * sin(lat+(90*DEG_TO_RAD));
v[0][4][2]= radius * (cos(lat+(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * cos(lon));

//D
v[0][2][0]= radius *  (cos(lat) * sin(lon+(90*DEG_TO_RAD)));
v[0][2][1]=  radius * sin(lat);
v[0][2][2]= radius * (cos(lat) * cos(lon+(90*DEG_TO_RAD)));


// Side ABD
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON); // Start drawing a quad primitive
    glVertex3f(v[0][0][0], v[0][0][1], v[0][0][2]);  //A
    glVertex3f(v[0][5][0], v[0][6][1], v[0][7][2]);  //B
    glVertex3f(v[0][2][0], v[0][2][1], v[0][2][2]);  //D



//A
v[1][0][0]= radius *  (cos(lat) * sin(lon));
v[1][0][1]= radius * sin(lat);
v[1][0][2]= radius * (cos(lat) * cos(lon));

//D
v[1][8][0]= radius * cos(lat) * sin(lon+(90*DEG_TO_RAD));
v[1][9][1]= radius * sin(lat);
v[1][10][2]= radius * (cos(lat) * cos(lon+(90*DEG_TO_RAD)));

//C
v[1][2][0]= radius *  (cos(lat-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * sin(lon));
v[1][2][1]= radius * sin(lat-(90*DEG_TO_RAD));
v[1][2][2]= radius * (cos(lat-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * cos(lon));

// Side ADC
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(v[1][0][0], v[1][0][1], v[1][0][2]);  //A
    glVertex3f(v[1][11][0], v[1][12][1], v[1][13][2]);  //D
    glVertex3f(v[1][2][0], v[1][2][1], v[1][2][2]);  //C



//A
v[2][0][0]= radius *  (cos(lat) * sin(lon));
v[2][0][1]= radius * sin(lat);
v[2][0][2]= radius * (cos(lat) * cos(lon));

//C
v[2][14][0]= radius *  (cos(lat-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * sin(lon));
v[2][15][1]= radius * sin(lat-(90*DEG_TO_RAD));
v[2][16][2]= radius * (cos(lat-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * cos(lon));

//E
v[2][2][0]= radius *  (cos(lat) * sin(lon-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)));
v[2][2][1]= radius * sin(lat); 
v[2][2][2]= radius * (cos(lat) * cos(lon-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)));

// Side ACE
glColor3f(0.5, 0.3, 0.1);
    glVertex3f(v[2][0][0], v[2][0][1], v[2][0][2]);  //A
    glVertex3f(v[2][17][0], v[2][18][1], v[2][19][2]);  //C
    glVertex3f(v[2][2][0], v[2][2][1], v[2][2][2]);  //E

//A
v[3][0][0]= radius *  (cos(lat) * sin(lon));
v[3][0][1]= radius * sin(lat);
v[3][0][2]= radius * (cos(lat) * cos(lon));

//E
v[3][20][0]= radius *  (cos(lat) * sin(lon-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)));
v[3][21][1]= radius * sin(lat); 
v[3][22][2]= radius * (cos(lat) * cos(lon-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)));

//B
v[3][2][0]= radius *  (cos(lat+(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * sin(lon));
v[3][2][1]= radius * sin(lat+(90*DEG_TO_RAD));
v[3][2][2]= radius * (cos(lat+(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * cos(lon));

// Side AEB
glColor3f(1.0, 0.8, 0.7);
    glVertex3f(v[3][0][0], v[3][0][1], v[3][0][2]);  //A
    glVertex3f(v[3][23][0], v[3][24][1], v[3][25][2]);  //E
    glVertex3f(v[3][2][0], v[3][2][1], v[3][2][2]);  //B
glEnd();


/*
    //Square BECD
    glColor3f(0.1, 0.3, 0.1);
    glVertex3f((radius * cos(lat+(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * sin(lon)), (radius * sin(lat+(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * sin(lon)), (radius * cos(lon)));  //headB
    glVertex3f((radius * cos(lat) * sin(lon-(90*DEG_TO_RAD))), (radius * sin(lat) * sin(lon-(90*DEG_TO_RAD))), (radius * cos(lon-(90*DEG_TO_RAD))));  //headE
    glVertex3f((radius * cos(lat-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * sin(lon)), (radius * sin(lat-(90*DEG_TO_RAD)) * sin(lon)), (radius * cos(lon)));  //headC
    glVertex3f((radius * cos(lat) * sin(lon+(90*DEG_TO_RAD))), (radius * sin(lat) * sin(lon+(90*DEG_TO_RAD))), (radius * cos(lon+(90*DEG_TO_RAD))));  //headD
    glEnd();
*/
```

Let's not consider to draw the square base of the pyramid, the problem already exists from before! For some reason it just renders a mess! I do not get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm interesting problem, if I understand your problem correctly, here's how I would do it.  Let your generated point on the unit sphere be `(a,b,c)` with `a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1` where the sphere is centered at the origin, then we draw a line through `(a,b,c)` and its opposite `(-a,-b,-c)`.  It's easy to determine the equation of this line.  Next we find a line in 3d perpendicular to this line, there are infinitely many choices.  With these 2 lines we can find the 2 planes determined by these 2 lines and their intersection with the sphere will give you the coordinates of the pyramid.  Again there are infinitely many choices depending on the 2nd line you choose (think of this as taking holding one line fixed and another line perpendicular to it at its midpoint and free to rotate)

Answer (score 1):

`GL_POLYGON` draws a *single*, **convex** polygon with all the vertices you give it.

Since you're only drawing triangles you should switch to `GL_TRIANGLES`.